# vue2 : splice data element array within component

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, array-splice

I'm trying to splice nested data inside vue component,
I wonder if this approach is correct to do in this task, at the moment, the behavior is that the data in the template doesn't update

```
template:`{{theData}}`,

props: ['data'],

data: function(){
theData = this.data;
return{theData},
},

methods:{
  spliceData : function(index,parent){
        this.theData.splice(index,1);
        return this.theData;
    }
}
```

May I use computed o watchers methods? I'm quite confusing if is possible to do it using these approach..

Thank you

Comment: where did you call spliceData()?

Answer (score 0):

there seems to be quite few things "off" in the code you posted, I'm not sure you'd get anything back, and I'm not certain I understand the question, so I'll rephrase it as I understand it.

> Can I splice an array in a component?

of course, it's just javascript you can pass the variable/array you want to splice and it will splice it.

however, I'm guessing what you may be asking is ...

> Can I splice a variable passed as prop to a child component, and have it be updated in the parent?

the answer to that is no (and yes)

- no, you can't change the data in the child and have it be reflected in the parent on it's own
- yes, you do have other options.

  - vuex - a flux library that handles a single source of data, but if comes off a little complicated when you're just getting to know vuex (or flux/redux)
  - pass function as parameter. This is one method I don't see discussed very often, and I assume for good reason, but it works.
  - using a bus
  - using emit

you can google up on these to figure out which suits you best, I'd say either emit for a simple app, or vuex for more complicated.